# regular expression property title case (Lt)

Tags: regex

I use the property **Lt** to match a capitalized letter at the start of a word (title case).

My regular expression (regex101.com) is only the property `\p{Lt}` and my test string is `Title Case`.

The result is: **no match**. The properties Ll and Lu give correct results. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: But there is no letters from the `Lt` category in `Title Case`.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html: \p{Lt} or \p{Titlecase_Letter}: a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is capitalized. That applies to both Title and Case, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p{Lt}` only matches the Unuicode letters from the [`Lt` cateogry](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/LT):

```html
U+01C5   ǅ   Latin Capital Letter D with Small Letter Z with Caron
U+01C8   ǈ   Latin Capital Letter L with Small Letter J
U+01CB   ǋ   Latin Capital Letter N with Small Letter J
U+01F2   ǲ   Latin Capital Letter D with Small Letter Z
U+1F88   ᾈ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Psili and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F89   ᾉ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Dasia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F8A   ᾊ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Psili and Varia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F8B   ᾋ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Dasia and Varia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F8C   ᾌ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Psili and Oxia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F8D   ᾍ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Dasia and Oxia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F8E   ᾎ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Psili and Perispomeni and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F8F   ᾏ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Dasia and Perispomeni and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F98   ᾘ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Psili and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F99   ᾙ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Dasia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F9A   ᾚ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Psili and Varia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F9B   ᾛ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Dasia and Varia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F9C   ᾜ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Psili and Oxia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F9D   ᾝ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Dasia and Oxia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F9E   ᾞ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Psili and Perispomeni and Prosgegrammeni
U+1F9F   ᾟ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Dasia and Perispomeni and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FA8   ᾨ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Psili and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FA9   ᾩ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Dasia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FAA   ᾪ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Psili and Varia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FAB   ᾫ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Dasia and Varia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FAC   ᾬ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Psili and Oxia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FAD   ᾭ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Dasia and Oxia and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FAE   ᾮ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Psili and Perispomeni and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FAF   ᾯ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Dasia and Perispomeni and Prosgegrammeni
U+1FBC   ᾼ   Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Prosgegrammeni
U+1FCC   ῌ   Greek Capital Letter Eta with Prosgegrammeni
U+1FFC   ῼ   Greek Capital Letter Omega with Prosgegrammeni
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BaUn7/1).

What you want is `\b\p{Lu}`, the regex will match any uppercase letter that is not immediately preceded with a word char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BaUn7/2).

Depending on what contexts you want to math the uppercase letter in, the regex can also look like

- `(?<!\p{L})\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter not immediately preceded with any letter
- `(?<!\S)\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter not immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char.

Comment: Thank you. The Unicode category “Titlecase Letter” was not known to me.